# send only info level logs to zipkin

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

In the micro-services based architecture , I have a services which helps me to fetch order details .

Internally order details fetches - customer details , delivery details , product details .  We have all services developed and the architecture is established.

No we export everything to zipkin with the sampler rate of 100%. So it includes - INFO level logs and error level logs also , currently it is useful but we already have separate mechanism for ERROR level logs.

so , i just want to skip the zipkin logging for ERROR level log and  send only INFO level logs to zipkin

I tried searching through, but could not get any help, i am newbie to micro services

any help is appreciated , thank you

Answer (score 1):

[Zipkin](https://zipkin.io/) is a solution for distributed tracing. Specifically it allows to track latency problems in distributed system. Also it's a greate tool for debugging/investigating problems in your application. So by definition it requires to collect successful and failed traces. However [traces](https://zipkin.io/pages/architecture.html) have nothing to do with logging.

Assuming you mean controlling the logging level of Zipkin server, then you can just set it using [--logging.level.zipkin2=INFO](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/blob/master/zipkin-server/README.md#logging).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem. You don't send logs to Zipkin. You send spans to Zipkin. Zipkin has nothing to do with logs.